# "Lightbox effect" on app (android studio + java)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, lightbox

Searched everywhere with no results
(Android studio 2022.1.1 + java + Material 3)
I wanna obtain a sort of lightbox effect on tapping an image (or pressing a button), I've tryied to create a fragment with a full screen with no header but I donìt know how to obtain the semi-trasparency on the parts of the screen not covered by the image..
Maybe FragmentDialog? but can't set effect on background, I obtain an opaque form (as all the others)